# How do I manually initiate the 404 handler in Slim 3?

Tags: php, httpresponse, slim, slim-3

We already know how to add a custom 404 `notFoundHandler` in Slim 3:

```
$container['notFoundHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response) use ($c) {
        return $c->view->render($response, 'pages/404.html.twig') 
            ->withStatus(404)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    };
};
```

I would like to trigger this manually in one of my routes.

In Slim 2, we were able to do something like `$app->notFound()`.  What is the equivalent in Slim 3?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to throw a new instance of \Slim\Exception\NotFoundException

```
throw new \Slim\Exception\NotFoundException($request, $response);
```

Comment: I found this answer on Google, so i'm commenting for new users. For Slim 4, use HttpNotFoundException, like: `throw new \Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException($request, "Resource not found")`

Comment: How do you use the second argument? Say to display it on the error page.